# How do i select a random cell in a csv

Tags: python, csv, random

I have a CSV file that is random words only. No header.

For example:

```
"dawn","go","test","these","swung"
"joy","frequently","seven","congress"
```

My code does not select a random cell and returns the error:

```
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
```

My code is:

```
    def random_select(self):

        csv_reader = csv.reader("randomwords.csv")       
        words = list(csv_reader)
        random_names = random.choice(words)
        readcsv = csv_reader[random_names][random_names]

        print(''.join(readcsv))
```

Comment: Not really familiar with using the csv module aside from `with open()...` syntax. Couldn't you import the `random` module, count the number of rows in your csv file, generate a random integer, and then select the row at that position?

Comment: What do you hope `csv_reader[random_names][random_names]` should do? I find it hard to say anything more than what's already in the error message, but probably your imagination is richer than mine for you to come up with this code in the first place.

Comment: `csv.reader("randomwords.csv")` creates a reader which returns `[['r'], ['a'], ['n'], ['d'], ['o'], ['m'], ['w'], ['o'], ['r'], ['d'], ['s'], ['.'], ['c'], ['s'], ['v']]`. If you want to read from a file, you need to `open` it and then pass the file handle to `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a refactoring with the immediate errors fixed.

```py
# There is no class here and no self here -- don't use self as argument
def random_select():
    # Open a file handle, pass it to the CSV reader instance
    with open("randomwords.csv") as r:
        # Read all words from all lines into a single list
        words = [word for line in csv.reader(r) for word in line]
    # Pick out two random words
    return ''.join([random.choice(words), random.choice(words)])
```

Internal functions should usually just `return` a result; the caller can then `print` the result if they want to.

With a short input list, there is a nontrivial probability that the same word will be picked at random twice. It's not even clear from your question whether you actually want two random words from the list, but this is my best guess as to what the code should produce. If you want something else, hopefully it should now be obvious what to change.

Reading the CSV file into memory again every time you call this function is horribly inefficient; probably refactor the code to read the list into memory once, then pick out random words from the list of words whenever you need more.

A CSV file is probably not at all ideal for this sort of use case. The standard way to store a list of words since the late 1960s at least is a simple text file, one word or phrase per line.

Comment: perfect thank you, this did exactly what I needed with way less code.

Comment: Thanks, I was focused on the random selection part and just trying to get some guidance written to point him in the right direction before I started my work day.

Answer (score 0):

`random_names` is a single string picked from `words`.  So `words` is subscriptable, but nothing else.

If you are just looking for "random_itemrandom_item" to be generated as a string,

```
    def random_select(self):

        csv_reader = csv.reader("randomwords.csv")       
        lines = list(csv_reader)
        words = lines[0]

        print(''.join(random.choices(words, k=2)))
```

Comment: I've never used the random function much.  Kudos to the good description at https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/ for informing me about random.choices() instead of random.choice()

Comment: thanks for the input. copying your code I got a 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found' Error.

Comment: The argument to `csv.reader` should be a file handle, and iterating over it returns a list of lists of words (each line is one list of strings). Having a one-line CSV file is kind of insane anyway. Probably a better design would be to have one word per line in a regular text file.

Comment: yes, ``words=list(csv_reader)`` generates a list of items per row of the csv file (a list of lists).  Edited to get you where you are looking.

Comment: This still picks out random letters from the file name string, not from the file it names.

Answer (score 0):

code that worked:

```
def Generate(self):
        rcolumn = random.randint(0, 10)
        rrow = random.randint(0, 66)
        with open('randomwords.csv', 'r') as f:
            mycsv = csv.reader(f)
            mycsv = list(mycsv)
            print(mycsv[rrow][rcolumn])
```

Comment: Uh, you are hardcoding assumptions about the number of entries in the text file. Probably better to read it all into memory, then use the dimensions of the data you have in memory to decide on the limits.